very strange error HA k8s cluster with haproxy as load balancer
I am trying to create k8s cluster with haproxy as external  load balancer ( 2 haproxy nodes, 3 control planes , 3 workers) currently am still trying with 2 haproxy and 2 control planes
ERROR : connection between cluster and load balancer is not stable ,, sometimes its UP and then its DOWN again  and going in cycles and I didn't understand why
Logs of the proxy
image for logs
and when I try the cmd kubectl get nodes I get different errors (when haproxy is down )
kubectl get nodes
Unable to connect to the server: EOF
 kubectl get nodes
Error from server: etcdserver: request timed out
kubectl get nodes 
Error from server: etcdserver: leader changed

also I noticed the kube-apiserver pods have a high number of restarts.
 kubectl get pods -n kube-system -l component=kube-apiserver
NAME                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS           AGE
kube-apiserver-updevopskm2   1/1     Running   3742 (6m12s ago)   5d3h
kube-apiserver-updevopskm3   1/1     Running   4037 (5m56s ago)   5d2h

this is my haproxy.cfg file
frontend apiserver
    bind *:6443
    mode tcp
    option tcplog
    default_backend apiserverbackendbackend apiserverbackend
    mode tcp
    option tcp-check
    balance roundrobin
    default-server inter 10s downinter 5s rise 2 fall 2 slowstart 60s maxconn 250 maxqueue 256 weight 100
    server updevopskm2 ip:6443  check
    server updevopskm3 ip:6443  check

i couldn't find any relevant solution
